# How to install ros hydro on Nao V3?

Tags: ros-hydro, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I'm looking for a good how to for installing ROS Hydro version on Nao.
Is there any step-by-step how to? I've googled a lot and found nothing for hydro, the latest instructions was on groovy. I'm totally new with ROS and catkin system and couldn't find my way through those tutorials to build hydro and make it work on Nao V3.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85346/how-to-install-ros-hydro-on-nao-v3?/) by [nkhdiscovery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7251/nkhdiscovery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working in install NAO, but only it is posible in Ros Fuerte

Before you install ROS Electric/groovy/fuerte or Hydro is recommend to look at robot-specific installation options instead.

http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started#Installing_NAOqi

---

Originally posted by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) with karma: 52 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkhdiscovery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7251/nkhdiscovery/) on 2013-10-24**:
Hmm, I'm sorry for the delay, I can't find what you mean by "robot-specific installation options" . Yes, I also was looking around to find differences in drivers and modules for ros on the Nao v3 and v4 but got nothing, would you please make it clearer for me?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-12-10**:
Use Fuerte, I did it with this

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-12-11**:
http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started